# Django Url pattern (add paramether), and view

Tags: django

There is urls.py pattern.

```
    url(r'^notice/(?P<article>[0-9]\d+)/', web.views.notice),
```

Here is views.py

```
def notice(request, article):
    data = article
return render(request, "notice.html")
```

However, web brower shows 404 Error.
If I remove add parameter, it is ok.

What I am wrong?

Intended result (Blog style, not get parameter)
/notice/1, /notice/2, ...

Comment: What is `article`? Is it a digit from 0 to 9?

Comment: Hello Matt. It means digit

Comment: Here is example I tried. http://example.com/notice/1

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that `[0-9]\d+` is expecting at least a 2-digit number, one digit for the `[0-9]` and then one or more digits following that due to the `\d+`. I believe what you really want is just

```
url(r'^notice/(?P<article>\d+)$', 'web.views.notice')
```

Comment: Still not solved. Django can't find webpage (404 Error)

Comment: Try adding apostrophes around `'web.views.notice'` as in my edit.

Comment: I solved problems.url(r'^notice/(?P<article>\d+)/$ ', web.views.notice)

Comment: But the view is expecting something called `article`.

Comment: Thanks your cooperation sir.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use d???

```
url(r'^issue/(?P<issue_id>[0-9]+)$', views.issue, name='issue'),
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>.*)$', login_required(views.ProjectView.as_view()), name='project'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question you asked, I am getting that you want to display the data on the template based on the parameter passed in the URL.Let me try to explain it step by step:

1. First lets say you have the following url:

   url(r'^notice/(?P`<article>`\d+)$', views.notice,name="notice")
2. Now lets define the view for fetching the data from the model, based on the parameter in the URL, i am assuming you are passing the PK in the URL:

   def notice(request, article):

   data = YourModelName.objects.get(id=article)

   //Passing back the result to the template

   context={"article":data}

   return render(request, "notice.html",context)
3. Now in your template you can access the data as such:

   {{ article.field_name }}

Hope this helps you out!!!!